# Upload image to node/express and then s3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, dropzone.js, redux-form

I am writing a redux-form which updates user information to a database, the user information includes a profile picture of the user.

I want to upload the profile picture to s3 and update the s3 url link of the picture into the database.

This is the flow:

1. web reactjs client sends user information including image to node/express,
2. nodejs uploads the image to s3 and retrieves the URL
3. nodejs updates user infomation and URL into mongodb

I am relatively new when it comes to forms and images and after looking through multiple examples of redux-form, react-s3-uploader, react-dropzone etc. I am yet unable to figure how the image reaches node/express from reactjs.

Most of the examples, just falls short of explaining how the image is sent to the server, maybe it is something very simple.

Can someone help me with some example client react code and server nodejs code(express), so I get some direction on this.

I have seen examples (react-s3-uploader) of uploading the image from the browser directly to S3, but I want to send it to my server, retrieve the image URL and update the URL in a mongo database.

Comment: you should let the client upload directly to S3 using a presigned url that you generate in node/express. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

Comment: @BretzL thanks. I will explore this further.